# Mutable and Inmutable Deep/Shallow copies Python

Tags: python

I have a question about how Python manage deep and shallow copies.

From what I have read:

1. The shallow-copy *constructs a new compound object and then (to the
   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
   the original.*
2. The deep copy *constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.*

If you do:

```
a = list() 
b = a
a.append(1)
print(b)
```

It will show that b = [1]. If I change b it will modify a. If I change a it will modify b, as they are both pointing to the same list... (right?)

- So, If I have understood it correctly, does this means that Python
  manage shallow copies with **lists**?? Is this `b = a` a shallow copy??
- Do shallow/deep copies depend on the *mutability (Mutable/Inmutable) 
  of the classes*?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes it depends on mutability. if an object is immutable there no difference between shallow or deep copy

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns explains this well

Comment: Your example doesn't show any shallow or deep copies, so it's hard to know what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

- Shallow copy makes a copy of the outer level items in the list, whatever nested inside those items will still be copied by reference
- Deep copy goes through all nested items and copies each single one of them

---

Your example doesn't include copying, `a = b` will have both variables point to the same list.

Consider the following examples:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = copy.copy(a) # shallow copy, you can use b = list(a) too
a[0][0] = 5
# b[0][0] will be 5

a[0] = [0, 0]
# b[0] will not change
```

Why? Because shallow copy produces a copy of the elements in the list in the first level (`b[0]` is a copy of `a[0]`) but if `a[0]` is a list, anything inside that list is pointing to the same place as the elements in `b[0]`.

While deep copy keeps going and copying all the elements no matter how nested the elements are

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a) # deep copy
a[0][0] = 5
# b[0][0] will not change

a[0] = [0, 0]
# b[0] will not change
```

Comment: You've made a completely false statement here, `a = b` does not do anything different based on whether an object is mutable or immutable.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't know that about immutables. Edited, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html):

> - A *shallow* copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A *deep* copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

This interactive session might help you figure out the difference between shallow copy and deep copy:

```py
In [91]: import copy

In [92]: z = [100, -1]

In [93]: a = [1, 2, z]

In [94]: b = a

In [95]: c = copy.copy(a)

In [96]: d = copy.deepcopy(a)

In [97]: a[0] = 99

In [98]: z[-1] = 0

In [99]: a
Out[99]: [99, 2, [100, 0]]

In [100]: b
Out[100]: [99, 2, [100, 0]]

In [101]: c
Out[101]: [1, 2, [100, 0]]

In [102]: d
Out[102]: [1, 2, [100, -1]]
```

Notice that the assignment `b = a` does not create a copy of the list referenced by `a`, it simply binds a new name `b` to that list.

A graphical representation of the objects in memory may provide you with further insight into these concepts.

[image: screenshot from Python tutor online]

Answer (score 0):

Python **never** makes a copy with the assignment `=`, it just adds another way of referring to the same object.  From the [Zen of Python (PEP 20)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "Explicit is better than implicit."  If you want a copy you need to be explicit and ask for one.

```
a = list() 
b = a
a.append(1)
print(id(a), id(b))
1215215211272 1215215211272

import copy
c = copy.copy(a) # shallow copy
d = copy.deepcopy(a) # deep copy
print(id(a), id(c), id(a[0]), id(c[0]))
1215215211272 1215228911952 1215215269384 1215228911952
print(id(a), id(d), id(a[0]), id(d[0]))
1215215211272 1215228911952 1215215224136 1215228911952
```

The `id` will tell you if an object is the same or if it's a copy.  In this case `deepcopy` didn't actually copy the integer, because it didn't need to - integers are immutable and you can't tell the difference between a copy and the original.